# only-of-class with pure CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to hide `.meta` elements only if there are not other `.meta` elements in the list.
Basically I need the same behavior of `:only-of-type` but for classes.

So, if I have:

```
<table>
    <tr class="meta"><td>lorem</td></tr>
    <tr class="row"><td>row</td></tr>
</table>
```

`.meta` will be hidden

If I have:

```
<table>
    <tr class="meta"><td>lorem</td></tr>
    <tr class="row"><td>row</td></tr>
    <tr class="meta"><td>lorem</td></tr>
</table>
```

`.meta` will be shown.

The CSS should looks like:

```
.meta:only-of-class { display: none; }
```

Is it possible with pure CSS?

**Edit:**

I've even tried with this markup (not much W3C compilant but who care):

```
<table>
    <tr><th class="meta"><lorem</th><tr>
    <tr class="row"><td>row</td></tr>
</table>
```

With this CSS:

```
th:only-of-type { display: none; }
```

But it doesn't work (and here I've not really idea of why it doesn't)

Comment: No, because there's no way for a subsequent element to affect a previous element.

Comment: But `:only-of-type` exists and it's a valid CSS property.

Comment: So? That's a different selector entirely and built into the browser.

Comment: Ok but it's not a so weird request have a similar selector that uses classes instead of element type. So I thought that it could exists.

Comment: Isn't .meta:only-of-type enough?

Comment: No it doesn't work. (no JS sorry :( )

Comment: @FezVrasta the `:only-of-type` works in a very unexpected way (as many think), it fails if the parent element has **more than** 1 element, that means the parent need to have only 1 child, and that child should have the type going before the `:only-of-type`.

Comment: @Roberto Reale: No, that's because the element type is `tr`, and there's more than one of those there.

Comment: "not much W3C compilant but who care" Joke's on you - the browser cares. What you have so sloppily thrown together is completely and utterly nonsensical markup - a `th` is a table cell, just like a `td`, so a `th` cannot be a container for a `td`. What the browser is doing is making that `th` empty, so what you're hiding is actually nothing more than an empty cell.

Comment: Yes I've added an extra <td> but I was talking about the mix of th and tr on tbody. I'm developing a desktop app that uses HTML with Chrome CEF so I don't need to follow W3C

Answer (score 2):

A possibile workaround could be contrived by using a *dummy* item in those lists which contain more than one *.meta* element:

```
<ul>
    <li class="meta">lorem</li>
    <li class="row">row</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="meta">dummy</li>
    <li class="meta">lorem</li>
    <li class="row">row</li>
    <li class="meta">lorem</li>
</ul>
```

Then you would give to every item the *display: none* property, and override it only when you have more than one *.meta* sibling:

```
ul > .meta {
    display: none;
}

ul > .meta ~ .meta {
    display: list-item;
}
```

Comment: But this will hide the first .meta and display the others

Comment: It is indeed.  And it should be used only when you have more than one .meta item.  Like this http://jsfiddle.net/JQtHD/1/.

Comment: @RobertoReale do you really understand the OP's problem? In fact the list can have only 1 item of `.meta`, in that case, the `.meta` item should be hidden. But your solution can't solve that particular case.

Comment: @KingKing Did you take a look at the jsfiddle?  It solves both the case when you have just one .meta item and the case when you have more than one. It this latter case you just add a dummy .meta item (which doesn't show up).

Comment: The problem is **How do you know when to insert the dummy item into the ul**? If you know how to do so, you can just add another class to the item (which is the only 1 having `.meta`), apply any style to that class (including `display:none`).

Comment: This is up to whatever generates the html code.  Of course it's applicable with totally static, '80-style web pages...

Comment: @BoltClock So is this some kind of better workaround http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/JQtHD/2/ ?

Comment: @King King: I think it's up to the OP's discretion what makes one workaround "better" than another. What is for sure, however, is the fact that there is no pure CSS solution.

Comment: Okay thanks, so there's not a pure CSS solution... Keeping it open in case of future implementations of CSS properties. Thanks

Comment: @Fez Vrasta: There is a proposal in Selectors 4 that would make this possible, however since it's not implemented and still subject to change I'm not sure if I should post it right now. I can if you want, but it's not going to work anyway.